# Creating Holes in Cylinder for Lightsaber

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm trying to create the graflex lightsaber, and im almost done. Although, I need help cutting 2 types of holes on the cylinder mesh (main body)

1. Circular hole in the mesh (Shown with arrow and circles) to reveal the geometry (the one with two small pins) I have under it
2. A square hole just above the word "cut"

You can refer to the reference image below

Thank you guys! I'd appreciate help

[image]

[image: Reference Image]

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ci1jBOm_5NY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a few pictures that I can set up to show you. First, you add 3 loopcuts through the area you are working in. After that, you select 4 faces to make the inset for the rectangle and then 6 for the circle. I select the inner faces after the inset on the area to be turned into a circle, and duplicate it and separate it from the mesh. In object mode, I select that set of faces and use Looptools > Circle to round them into a circle after shifting the view to top view down with selection by pressing Shift Numpad 7. Here I then turn on the magnet and select Faces and then just press G to grab and confirm without moving it - the circle is then projected to the cylinder underneath. Join them back together with ctrl-J and enter edit mode -  and then delete the faces underneath , and scale the circle to fit the hole.  I used alt-M top merge at last by selecting the outer ring vert and then the one in the circle. After completely welded back together, I inset the faces to create another edge loop and then delete the inner faces for the circle and the rectangle.[image: step1][image: step2][image: step3][image: step4][image: step5 shift numpad 7][image: step 6][image: step7][image: step 8][image: step 9]

Answer (score 0):

A faster way to punch a hole in a mesh is to use **Knife Project** and delete the selected faces with X. It's great when you have an organic shape and doing it as shown in the other post is not time-efficient.

Comment: If you don't mind ngons, then knife project can work but then you might as well go with BoolTool for that matter. Mine was to avoid a mess.